# Install4j - autoupdate from 'external launcher'

Tags: install4j

Is there any way how to put autoupdate feature working with 'external launcher' or with installer without laucnher? Or autoupdate feature works with 'generated launcher' only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can call the update downloader from an external launcher, the update downloader has no way to shut down the launcher in case it needs to execute an update installer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My situation is: I have Java application which is transformed to exe file with exe4j. And in this exe I need to use install4j autoupdate feature. Is it possible to call Install4j API from my code in this situation? How to put i4jruntime.jar to classpath of my application? Will be this done by install4j automatically? In docs is written that this jar will be placed to claspath automaticaly, but will this work for external launcher? External launcher is just calling external application isn't it? If I call Install4j API in this situation I got: NoClassDefFound exception

Comment: For executables generated by exe4j, i4jruntime.jar is not added to the class path, you would have to add it yourself, it's located in .install4j/j4jruntime.jar